# Convert columns with x, y, z and velocity coordinates to a picture

Tags: matlab

I have an array with 4 columns:
x coordinates,
y coordinate,
z coordinate,
and velocity magnitude.
Is there a simple way to convert this data to a heat map?

Thanks.

Comment: Like a coloured surface? Try `surf`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [`scatter3`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter3.html):

```
scatter3(x, y, z, 20, v);
colormap jet
```